# Add a list of arbitrary lists in elementwise Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

In Scheme, we can add two lists `l1,l2` using `(map + l1 l2)`. Now suppose we have a list of n lists each of length m. For example, consider `(define q '((0 1 0) (1 0 0) (0 0 1)))`. Using `apply` and `map` it should be a one liner to add the elements of this list elementwise, and obtain `(1,1,1)`. I think it should look something like this:
`(map + (apply __ q))`
please help me fill in the blank (or suggest an alternative).

Comment: `(apply map + q)`?

Comment: @Sylwester lol yep. If you put it as an answer with a quick explanation of how it works, i'll accept.

Comment: I tried to explain how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190645/849891).

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the pointer. Up-voted your answer.

Comment: as long as it was helpful. :) glad that it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Racket have an `call-arguments-limit` concerning the `apply` call?
In common lisp this is the case. And one would circumvent apply by this strategy:

```
(define q '((0 1 0) (1 0 0) (0 0 1)))

(define (add l1 l2) (map + l1 l2)) ; adds two lists of any length element wise

(foldr add '(0 0 0) q) 
; reduce over list of list q by element-wise addition of the inner lists
```

Starting value is `'(0 0 0)` to which the inner lists of `q` are added/accumulated element wise.