# Understanding map pattern for n-ary operations on n lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme, higher-order-functions, map-function

I understand that `(map f '(a b c d))` is `'(f(a) f(b) f(c) f(d))` by applying function `f` to each element in the list. But the following seems to be hard to understand for me:

```
(map * '(1 2) '(1 2))
```

The output should be `'(1 4)`. How  come?

Can anyone explain how `map` pattern works in Scheme when we apply an *n*-ary operation to *n* lists?

Answer (score 0):

`map` takes the ith elements of the provided lists, passes them to the n-ary operation, and stores the result at ith position of the returned list.

So, `(map f '(a b c d) '(A B C D))` will be equal to `((f a A) (f b B) (f c C) (f d D))`.
More than two lists are handled similarly.

Comment: Is not `(map f '(a b c d) '(A B C D))` should be equals to `(list (f 'a 'A) (f 'b 'B) (f 'c 'C) (f 'd 'D))`?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes, it is. I just mentioned it in the quoted form like OP did in his question.

Answer (score 0):

`'(f (a) f (b) f (c) f (d))` is and can only be `(f (a) f (b) f (c) f (d))` after evaluation.

`map` for one list argument can be defined like this:

```
(define (map1 fn lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (fn (car lst))
            (map1 fn (cdr lst)))))
```

and `(map add1 '(1 2 3))` can be substituted with

```
(cons (add1 '1) 
      (cons (add1 '2)
            (cons (add1 '3)
                  '())))
; ==> (2 . (3 . (4 . ())))
; ==> (2 3 4)
```

Now `map` takes at least one list argument and it expects the function passed to take one or each. Thus `(map * '(1 2) '(1 2))` is the same as:

```
(cons (* '1 '1)
      (cons (* '2 '2)
            '()))
; ==> (1 . (4 . ())) 
; ==> (1 4)
```

I'm not entirely sure if you are having trouble grasping `map` or how lists are made. If it is the latter you should really make it top priority to be able to see `(1 2 (3 4))` and understand that `3` is the `caaddr` since the pairs are `(1 . (2 . ((3 . (4 . ())) . ())))`. Read it right to left while looking at the pairs and you see it. If it's `map` then you need to implement them. It is the best way to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

To truly understand something is best to implement it ourselves.

The map for 1-argument functions is easy, it's

```
(define (map1 f1  xs)
  (cons (f1   (car xs))
        (map1 f1
              (cdr xs))))
```

(adding the base case is left as an exercise). Similarly for two,

```
(define (map2 f2  xs  ys)
  (cons (f2   (car xs)  (car ys))
        (map2 f2
              (cdr xs)  (cdr ys))))
```

and three,

```
(define (map3 f3  xs  ys  zs)
  (cons (f3   (car xs)  (car ys)  (car zs))
        (map3 f3
              (cdr xs)  (cdr ys)  (cdr zs))))
```

We can use the same template for any *n*-argument function to be mapped over any *n* lists to take the *n* arguments from:

```
 map_n:
        xs:  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5 ...
        ys:  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5 ...
        zs:  z1  z2  z3  z4  z5 ...
        ...........................
              ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
              f   f   f   f   f
              =   =   =   =   =
    results: r1  r2  r3  r4  r5 ...
```

- related: [Matrix multiplication in scheme, List of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184095/matrix-multiplication-in-scheme-list-of-lists/52190645#52190645)