# Scheme / Racket : transposing lists with map and lambda

Tags: list, scheme, racket, transpose

I'm currently trying to code a procedure which gets a list of lists and returns a list of lists, which contains each first item of the input lists. For example I'll provide you with a Input and Output.

Input:

```
(list (list 1 5) (list 2 6) (list 3 7) (list 4 8)))
```

Output:

```
(list (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7 8))
```

My idea was to build a somewhat map procedure using lambda for function. I'm currently struggling on mapping any function on combined list elements, since map only processes a single item on the list (to my understanding).

Could anyone provide me with helpful insights?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about lists or tuples... parentheses are syntax for tuples in python but you have the word list so not to sure what the input looks like

Comment: @DrewNicolette in Scheme parens are for lists, so it's OK.

Comment: @DrewNicolette Thanks for answering, but Will Ness is totally right about Scheme syntax. If you want to, feel free to take a look on his answer in this thread. It made clear to me, how to handle the recursive map function and lambda for several lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Scheme / Racket with

```
(apply map list (list (list 1 5) (list 2 6) (list 3 7) (list 4 8)))
```

which in DrRacket returns

```
'((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8))
```

Basically, calling `(apply map list [a b c ... n])` (in *pseudocode*), is the same as calling

```
(map list a b c ... n)
```

The argument list is *"opened up"*, so to speak.

- cf. [Matrix multiplication in scheme, List of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184095/matrix-multiplication-in-scheme-list-of-lists/52190645#52190645)

`(lambda x x)` could be used instead of `list`, too:

```
(apply map (lambda x x) (list ....... ))
```

This is because `map` *can* be used with several lists as its inputs, not just one. In such a case the number of arguments to the lambda function must match the number of input lists.

A special case is `(lambda x ...)` where `x` is not enclosed in parentheses. This means such a lambda function can be applied to *any* number of arguments, which will all be collected and passed in *as a list*. So `(lambda x x)` will act just the same as the built-in `list` does, and can be seen as its implementation.

And by the way, this isn't "merging", it is "transposition".