# Looking for clarification on 'map' in Racket

Tags: matrix, scheme, racket

new to stackoverflow and new to racket. I've been studying racket using this documentation: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html

This is my understanding of map:

```
(map (lambda (number) (+ 1 number))'(1 2 3 4))
```

this assigns `'(1 2 3 4)` to variable `number` ,then map performs `(+ 1 '(1 2 3 4))`.

but when I see things like:

```
(define (matrix_addition matrix_a matrix_b)
  (map (lambda (x y) (map + x y)) matrix_a matrix_b))
```

I get very lost. I assume we're assigning two variables `x` and `y`, then performing `(map + x y)`,but I don't understand what or how `(map + x y)` works.

Another one I'm having trouble with is

```
(define (matrix_transpose matrix_a)
  (apply map (lambda x x) matrix_a))
```

what does `(lambda x x)` exactly do?

Thank you so much for clarifying. As you can see I've been working on matrix operations as suggested by a friend of mine.

Comment: **this assigns '(1 2 3 4) to variable number** No it doesn't, where did you get that idea?

Comment: I guess I don't understand map at all then :(

Comment: you got great answers explaining all but the one last bit you asked about. that you can find explained in e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229540/scheme-racket-transposing-lists-with-map-and-lambda/53230520#53230520) (disclaimer - it is by me) and the one linked in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this assigns `'(1 2 3 4)` to variable `number` ,then `map` performs `(+ 1 '(1 2 3 4))`.

No, that's not what it does. `map` is a looping function, it calls the function separately for each element in the list, and returns a list of the results.

So first it binds `number` to `1` and performs `(+ 1 number)`, which is `(+ 1 1)`. Then it binds `number` to `2` and performs `(+ 1 number)`, which is `(+ 1 2)`. And so on. All the results are collected into a list, so it returns `(2 3 4 5)`.

Getting to your matrix operation, the matrix is represented as a list of lists, so we need nested loops, which are done using nested calls to `map`.

```
(map (lambda (x y) (map + x y)) matrix_a matrix_b)
```

The outer `map` works as follows: First it binds `x` and `y` to the first elements of `matrix_a` and `matrix_b` respectively, and performs `(map + x y)`. Then it binds `x` and `y` to the second elements of `matrix_a` and `matrix_b`, and performs `(map + x y)`. And so on for each element of the two lists. Finally it returns a list of all these results.

The inner `(map + x y)` adds the corresponding elements of the two lists, returning a list of the sums. E.g. `(map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))` returns `(5 7 9)`.

So all together this creates a list of lists, where each element is the sum of the corresponding elements of `matrix_a` and `matrix_b`.

Finally,

> what does `(lambda x x)` exactly do?

It binds `x` to the list of all the arguments, and returns that list. So `((lambda x x) 1 2 3 4)` returns the list `(1 2 3 4)`. It's basically the inverse of `apply`, which spreads a list into multiple arguments to a function.

```
(apply (lambda x x) some-list)
```

returns a copy of `some-list`.

Comment: Thank you so much! your explanation of how map works clarified everything for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to think about `map`:

```
(map f (list 1 2 3)) 
; computes 
(list (f 1) (f 2) (f 3))
```

and

```
(map f (list 1 2 3) (list 11 22 33)) 
; computes 
(list (f 1 11) (f 2 22) (f 3 33))
```

So your example with `+` becomes:

```
(map + (list 1 2 3) (list 11 22 33)) 
; computes 
(list (+ 1 11) (+ 2 22) (+ 3 33))
```

which is `(list 12 24 36)`.

In the beginning it with be clearer to write

```
(define f (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(map f (list 1 2 3) (list 11 22 33)))
```

but when you can get used to `map` and `lambda`, the shorthand

```
(map (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) (list 1 2 3) (list 11 22 33)))
```

is useful.

Answer (score 1):

> this assigns '(1 2 3 4) to variable number ,then map performs (+ 1 '(1 2 3 4)).

If it was that simple why the need for `map`. You could just do  `(+ 1 '(1 2 3 4))` directly. Here is an implementation of `map1` which is `map` that can only have one list argument:

```
(define (map1 fn lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (cons (fn (first lst))
            (map1 f (rest lst)))))
```

And what it does:

```
(map1 add1 '(1 2 3))
; ==> (cons (add1 1) (cons (add1 2) (cons (add1 3) empty)))
; same as (list (add1 1) (add1 2) (add1 3))
```

The real `map` accepts any number of list arguments and then expect the element function to take as many elements that there are list arguments. eg.

```
(map (lambda (l n s) (list l n s)) '(a b c) '(1 2 3) '($ % *))
; ==> ((a 1 $) (b 2 %) (c 3 *))
```

A very cool way to do this without knowing the number of elements is `unzip`

```
(define (unzip . lst)
  (apply map list lst))

(unzip '(a b c) '(1 2 3) '($ % *))
; ==> ((a 1 $) (b 2 %) (c 3 *))
```

So `apply` flattens the call to `(map list '(a b c) '(1 2 3) '($ % *))` and `list` takes arbitrary elements so it ends up working the same way as th eprevious example, but it will also work for other dimentions:

```
(unzip '(a b c d) '(1 2 3 4))
; ==> ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `map` is a function. This function can require one or more arguments. Followed by the function in the arguments lists are one or more lists.

`map` loops from first to the last element of the lists in parallel.
And feeds therefore the i-th position of each list as arguments to the function
and collects the result into a results list which it returns.

Now three short examples which would make it clear to you how map goes through the lists:

```
(map list '(1 2 3)) 
;; => '((1) (2) (3))

(map list '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) 
;; => '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))

(map list '(1 2 3) '(a b c) '(A B C))
;; => '((1 a A) (2 b B) (3 c C))
```