# Simplistic way to think of the apply function

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, apply, sicp

In trying to 'reduce' the `apply` function, is the correct a proper understanding?

For example for `(apply func args)`

1. Remove the `(apply`  and matching `)`.
2. Inset the `func` as the first element of the `args`, moving the outer quote in one level if necessary.

Here would be an application:

```
; (add-pairs '((1 2)(3 4))) --> (3 7)
(define (add-pairs ps)
  (if (null? ps) nil
     (cons (+ (car (car ps)) (cadr (car ps))) (add-pairs (cdr ps)))))
```

```
(apply add-pairs '(((1 2) (3 4))))
xxxxxxx                          x
; Remove the "(apply " and matching ")"
add-pairs '(((1 2) (3 4)))
------------^
; Insert the function into the args, moving the quote in one level if required.
(add-pairs '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

Is the above an accurate way to show how the `apply` gets added in, or am I missing anything?

Comment: `apply` is usually used when the arguments are calculated dynamically, so there's no parentheses to remove and no quote to move.

Comment: e.g.`(apply + list-of-numbers)`

Comment: @Barmar what about: `(apply + '(1 2))` --> `(+ 1 2)` there's a level of parens removed there, no?

Comment: Right, but why would you ever write that, since you could just write `(+ 1 2)` in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar No reason, I'm just trying to figure this stuff out.....

Comment: Don't think about it in terms of syntax, learn what it *does*.

Comment: It simply spreads a list into the argument list of the function.

Comment: That is, `(define ls (list a b c d)) (apply fn ls)` <-> `(fn a b c d)`. (It's almost the "reverse" of the `(lambda args body)` form - if you `((lambda args body) a b c d)`, `args` is the list `(list a b c d)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is unfortunate, as it only leaves *one* argument after "the opening of the parentheses". But yes, that's how I also think about it. The simpler the better, :) as long as it is correct.

Except that of course the values in the list are first evaluated, so it's not a simply-syntactical process. But as a basic example,

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3)) 
== 
(      +       1 2 3 )
```

i.e. the parens around the *arguments* is what goes away.

For a non-trivial example, see

- [Matrix multiplication in scheme, List of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184095/matrix-multiplication-in-scheme-list-of-lists/52190645#52190645)

Comment: that linked answer is so cool and really a mind-bender to follow, thanks for sharing.

Comment: BTW it also shows that `apply`  is more than that: `(apply list 1 2 3 '(4))` also works and returns `'(1 2 3 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you know Python. I personally think that `apply` in Scheme and star operator `*` in Python are quite similar.

Imagine you want to zip several lists, which were themselves packed inside a list. Trying to call

```py
list_of_lists = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
zip(list_of_lists)
```

would not give you `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`, so you write

```py
zip(*list_of_lists)
# here it's the same as
zip(list_of_lists[0], list_of_lists[1])
```

using the iterable unpacking operator `*`. A (pretty full) alternative to this in Racket/Scheme is using an apply function:

```lisp
(define list-of-lists '((1 2) (3 4)))
(apply zip list-of-lists)
;; here it's the same as
(zip (car list-of-lists) (cadr list-of-lists))
```

(If, of course, zip in Scheme was defined the same way as in Python, requiring arbitrary number of arguments)

But you can definitely see the difference here, the syntactic one. In Python version of `apply` we are 'applying' this `*` to arguments and then pass what was 'returned' to calling function (`zip`). Scheme acts like a functional language and reverses everything inside out (at least that's how I see it): you're 'applying' `apply` to a function and its arguments and then it handles everything itself.

The other significant difference is that, of course, `apply` in Scheme is a normal function, so we can write e.g.

```lisp
(define (apply-func-to-sum-and-args func args)
  (func + args))
(apply-func-to-sum-and-args apply (list 1 2 3))
;; returns 6
```

Though I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that this function cannot be written in pure Scheme and it calls some weird C function under the hood.

Comment: there is `zip` in Scheme, working with arbitrary number of arguments. it is called `map`. :) more specifically, `(map list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) ...)` == `(list (list 1 3) (list 2 4) ...)`.

Comment: @WillNess, oh, indeed!) I'm always forgetting that map in Scheme is itself variadic)

Comment: I'm not sure that the unpacking operator is a great way to think about `apply`, which takes an arbitrary number of arguments of which only the final argument must be a list. So `(apply + 2 4 6 '(8 10 12))` --> `42`. This allows `zip` to be implemented as: `(define (zip . xss) (apply map list xss))`, with `(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3) '(x y z))` --> `((a 1 x) (b 2 y) (c 3 z))`. Generally speaking, I think that matching language features from (very) different languages in an attempt to understand one of them is a bad and misleading strategy.